# Bigquery - Add full date range to each id

Tags: arrays, date, google-bigquery

How can i apply GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date[, INTERVAL INT64_expr date_part]) to each record in a dataset. I understand how to apply it to get a single date range from start to end, but don't know how to apply the same date array to each id.

Say i have two distinct ID's x and y with the following dates:

```
      |id|date
      --------------
    1 |x |2021-01-01
    2 |x |2021-01-03 
    3 |y |2021-01-06 
    4 |y |2021-01-09
```

and i want to fill in the date gap for each ID

How can i achieve the following output?

```
      |id|date
      --------------
    1 |x |2021-01-01 
    2 |x |2021-01-02 
    3 |x |2021-01-03
    4 |y |2021-01-06 
    5 |y |2021-01-07
    6 |y |2021-01-08
    7 |y |2021-01-09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select id, date from (
  select id, date, lead(date) over(partition by id order by date) next_date
  from `project.dataset.table`
), unnest(generate_date_array(date, next_date)) date 
where not next_date is null
-- order by date
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: hey, base on this example, if I want to copy last record from '2021-01-09' to current date, how to do it?
Such as
y |2021-01-09 until y |2021-06-22

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in standard SQL in BigQuery:

```
with data as (
  select 'x' as id, date '2021-01-01' as date
  UNION ALL
  select 'x' as id, date '2021-01-03' as date
  UNION ALL
  select 'y' as id, date '2021-01-06' as date
  UNION ALL
  select 'y' as id, date '2021-01-09' as date
)
  select d1.id, date
  from data d1 
    join data d2 
      on d1.id = d2.id 
      and d1.date < d2.date, unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(d1.date, d2.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as date;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! it seems to work fine. I used the answer below from Mikhail Berlyant because it fit more conveniently in my current query.

Comment: Happy to help. Consider voting up the answer if it helped :)  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)